# Fit canvas and image inside div

Tags: html, css

How can I keep the `image` and `canvas` fit inside the `outerWrapper`?

So basically I want to be able to change the `canvas` and `image` proportions by only changing the `outerWrapper`'s height and width.

## [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/45Lqfeyk/1/)

```
<div class="parent">

  <div class="outerWrapper">
  
    <div class="wrapper">
    
      <div Style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute;">
        <canvas width="275" height="412" Style="background-color: lightblue;opacity:0.5;"></canvas>
      </div>
      
      <div Style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: relative;">
        <img width="275" height="412" Style="position:relative;" src="http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=9d3a714" />
      </div>  
      
    </div>
    
  </div>
  
</div>
```

css

```
.parent{
  width: 800px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: pink;
  position:relative;
}
.outerWrapper{
  width:25%;
  height:75%;
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
  background-color: blue;
}
.wrapper{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Then you will have to get rid of image and canvas height `412px`. Keep height in percentages so that will take height relative to its parent.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `'412'` on img and canvas with `:auto;` or use percentages. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I have worked out like this. Please do let me know if its still not the way you want, Thanks.

And here is the link to my working : https://jsfiddle.net/45Lqfeyk/2/
HTML:

```
<div class="parent">      
   <div class="outerWrapper">
    <canvas width="275"   Style="background-color: lightblue;opacity:0.5;"></canvas>

    <img width="275"   src="http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=9d3a714" />

   </div>      
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent{
width: 800px;
height: 400px;
background-color: pink;
display: block;
}
.outerWrapper {
position: relative;
background: yellow;
max-width: 300px;
height:40%;
}
canvas {
position: absolute;
height: 60%;
width: 60%;
}
img {
position: absolute;
height: 50%;
width: 50%;
border: 1px solid black;
}
```